# Preload images from an Array of paths, then pass it to a component thats gonna use it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-component, preload

so i am creating a simple game and i render it if someone presses a start button on the first render. i want to **preload** all the images that the component is gonna use, so that when you hit the start button its already preloaded.

this is how the array of image paths look like:

```
const imagesArr = [
  "/src/images/cheetah-min.webp",
  "/src/images/dolphin-min.webp",
  "/src/images/gorilla-min.webp",
  "/src/images/lion-min.webp",
  "/src/images/tiger-min.webp",
  "/src/images/troll-min.webp",
  "/src/images/werewolf.webp",
  "/src/images/wolf-min.webp"
]
```

This is my **App.jsx**:

```
function App() {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="game-container">
      {!isPlaying ? (
        <div className="welcome-screen">
          <h1 className="welcome-heading">Welcome to the game</h1>
          <button
            className="start-btn"
            onClick={() => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                GAMESTARTS_SOUND.play();
                setIsPlaying(true);
              }, 3000);
            }}
          >
            Play the game
          </button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Game />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

as you can see there is this **Game** container that gets rendered if you press the play button. Inside that component im using the images. at the moment im just rendering them out using <img tags in the returned JSX from Game.jsx.

what I want is to preload the images before that component gets rendered? any ideas?